# Why conditioning on dataframe return NAN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some coordinate data, and it seems they are very dispersed. So, I want to keep all outliers that are 2 distance away from std. There are two problem:

```
# Load the data 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("map.csv")

# calculate mean and std of longitude columns
lat_mean = df[['pickup_latitude', 'dropoff_latitude']].mean()
lat_std = df[['pickup_latitude', 'dropoff_latitude']].std()


lon_mean = df[['pickup_longitude', 'dropoff_longitude']].mean()
lon_std = df[['pickup_longitude', 'dropoff_longitude']].std()
```

Then I want to keep all within 2 std away:

```
df[np.abs(df[['pickup_latitude', 'dropoff_latitude']] - lat_mean) < 2 * lat_std]
```

But I get `NAN`! Why??

Comment: Have you checked your other variables? Is any of those NaN, like one of the means or stds?

Comment: Note that you selected two columns to filter on; essentially a 2-column wide dataframe. So the indexing on the resulting boolean dataframe will work a bit differently. Specifically, you'll notice that the only non-NaN columns are the two columns used in your filter. Perhaps you should filter on just one column, or combine the two columns (using logical or), depending on what you want. Then you can index the dataframe with a boolean series, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Copied from a comment to a below answer: "that either lat-pick up ot lat-drop off are within 2std". That is clearer, and important information. You should add that to your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Do you want the rows where both `'pickup_latitude'` and `'dropoff_latitude'` are within 2 STD? Just one of the two columns? If the latter, which column?

That is, your question is imprecise. As is your code to accomplish it. After clarifying your intent, you will need to:

1. Use [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).
2. Row-wise, you have multiple conditions. Specify how to handle multiple conditions, since we cannot index with a multidimensional key

#### Example solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# example data
np.random.seed(234)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'lat_1': np.random.normal(35, 2, size= 500)
    , 'lat_2': np.random.normal(36, 2, size= 500)
    , 'long_1': np.random.normal(30, 5, size= 500)
    , 'long_2': np.random.normal(29, 5, size= 500)
})

lat_mean = df[['lat_1', 'lat_2']].mean()
lat_std = df[['lat_1', 'lat_2']].std()
long_mean = df[['long_1', 'long_2']].mean()
long_std = df[['long_1', 'long_2']].mean()

# both lat_1 + lat_2 < 2 STD from their respective means
sub_df = df.loc[
    (np.abs(df['lat_1'] - lat_mean[0]) < 2 * lat_std[0]) &
    (np.abs(df['lat_2'] - lat_mean[1]) < 2 * lat_std[1])
]

sub_df.shape # (458, 4)

# Either lat_1 or lat_2 < 2 STD from their respective means
sub_df = df.loc[
    (np.abs(df['lat_1'] - lat_mean[0]) < 2 * lat_std[0]) |
    (np.abs(df['lat_2'] - lat_mean[1]) < 2 * lat_std[1])
]

sub_df.shape # (497, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks @alexwhitworth Yes I'm confused myself. Honestly, I want to aggreated all lat columns, take ave and std, then remove all rows that either lat-pick up ot lat-drop off are within 2std. Same for longitude.